# adding randomly generated number into array and summing them up

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

im currently doing an assignment where we have a certain amount of people play a game and each player have an attempt of scoring. The scores will be randomly generated from 1-3. The only problem i have is to store the randomly generated value into the array and then summing them up. This way, i can produce a leader board that say something like "congrats (player name) your total score is (total score)). Any suggestion on how to do these's would be great or better yet, any other alternatives would be appreciated as well. So far i've been using a incremental counter to generate the total score but it keeps generating the same number over and over again e.g. (2,2,2,2...) (1,1,1,1,....)

```js
<HTML>
<!Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>The Foundation Page </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
function main()
    {
    randomnumber()
    totalscore()
    }
function randomnumber()
{
    var randomnumber;
    randomnumber = Math.random()*3;
    return(Math.floor(randomnumber+0.5));

}
function totalscore() 
{
    var n;
    var score = 0;
    number = randomnumber();
    for (n = 0 ; n < 11 ; ++n)
    {
        if (number == 0)
  {
            score = score + 0;
        }
        else if (number == 2)
        {
            score =score + 2;
        }
        else if (number == 3)
        {
            score =score + 3;
        }
    }
  document.write(score)
}


</SCRIPT>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
<BODY BGCOLOUR = "WHITE">
<H2>The Foundation Page </H2>
<HR>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript"> main() </SCRIPT>
<INPUT NAME = "dobutton" TYPE = "button" value = "Start game" on Click = "game()"> 
<INPUT NAME = "dobutton" TYPE = "button" value = "Leaderboard" on Click = "leader()">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Im not sure how to edit my post. Is there a way?

Comment: There is an edit button.

Comment: sorry bout that, i just wanted to hear some idea first for any better alternatives before i start coding

Comment: `number = randomnumber();` shouldn't that be inside your for loop?

Comment: Also, you should place your executing code in window.onload or JQuery's ready method. The main method is a Java thing.

Answer (score 1):

This may help, although you should try first before posting for solutions.

Create an empty array:

```
var myArray = [];
```

Add values to array (from your randomnumber() generator):

```
myArray.push(randomnumber());
myArray.push(randomnumber());
myArray.push(randomnumber());
```

Function to sum the values of some array (this is perhaps the most primitive but faster/efficient way to do it):

```
var sumElements = function(someArray) {
    if (someArray == null) return false;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = someArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        sum += someArray[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Call sumElements to find the sum:

```
sumElements(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to do what you need

```
var randomArray = [];
var randomSum = 0;
randomArray.push(randomnumber());
randomArray.push(randomnumber());
randomArray.push(randomnumber());

for(var i=0; i<randomArray.lenth; i++){
   randomSum += randomArray[i];
}
```